# how to correct the error "unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I execute this code it is giving error "unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'" which is because of the statements executed in the second for loop in which compiler is also giving warning of undefined names. I have defined these names separately in the same place where these names are used which is not required in Python. After execution of the first for loop in else body the compiler goes to print statement in the last of the code (this I have seen from the debugging features placed on a coding website). How to correct all this?

```
L = ['apples', 'oranges', 'kiwis', 'pineapples']

def stdDevOfLengths(L):
    if L == []:
        return 'NAN'
    else:
        for i in range(len(L)):
            sumL = 0
            sumL += L[i]
        mew = sumL / len(L)
        for i in range(len(L)):
            t , sum2 == [] , 0
            t[i] == index(L[i])
            sum2 += (t[i] - mew)^2  
        stdDev = (sum2/len(L))^0.5
        return stdDev

print(stdDevOfLengths(L))
```

Comment: Probably you want to do `sumL += len(L[i])`

Comment: Also, you'ld want to put `t, sum2 == [], 0` outside of the for-loop

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  We can't "fix" your code because you've failed to explain what you're trying to do.  Please learn to test your code in pieces; you have piled one mistake after another before doing any validation.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python compute standard deviation", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: Why do you keep reassigning empty list to ```t```, and also why the double equality sign ```==```. I would generally reconsider this line: ```t , sum2 == [] , 0```

Comment: Be aware that `^` is a bitwise XOR, not "to the power of". You presumably want the `**` operator here.

Comment: this mistake of ^ instead ** looks big so thank you for telling the code which Jadan provided is running fine I think to find a way to get rid of these silly mistakes....

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you need:

```
L = ['apples', 'oranges', 'kiwis', 'pineapples']

def stdDevOfLengths(L):
    if L == []:
        return 'NAN'
    else:
        sumL = 0
        for i in range(len(L)):
            sumL += len(L[i])
        mew = sumL / len(L)
        for i in range(len(L)):
            t , sum2 = {} , 0
            t[i] = len(L[i])
            sum2 += (t[i] - mew)**2  
        stdDev = (sum2/len(L))**0.5
        return stdDev

print(stdDevOfLengths(L))
```

print ----> 1.5

Comment: `sumL += i` is certainly not what is needed;  this will just compute the sum of the numbers from 0 to `len(L) - 1`, which doesn't help computing the mean of the lengths of the strings.

Comment: The code you provided is working fine and is near to the exact answer of 1.8. I need to find a way to get rid of doing such mistakes somehow on time....